# Do flexible quotes add an extra character to a string?

Tags: ruby, string, quotes

I was learning ruby through ruby koans when I faced these two functions:

```
def test_flexible_quotes_can_handle_multiple_lines
   *long_string = %{
   It was the best of times,
   It was the worst of times.
   }*
   assert_equal *54*, long_string.size
end

def test_here_documents_can_also_handle_multiple_lines
   *long_string = <<EOS
   It was the best of times,
   It was the worst of times.
   EOS*
   assert_equal *53*, long_string.size
end
```

The problem is I cannot understand where this extra character is coming from when using flexible quotes. Ruby koans says that both answers are correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd say it's a newline character after `%{`.

```
>> test = %{
">> foo
">> }
=> "\nfoo\n"
>> test.size
=> 5
>> test = %{foo
">> }
=> "foo\n"
>> test.size
=> 4
>> test = <<EOS
">> foo
">> EOS
=> "foo\n"
>> test.size
=> 4
```

Answer (score 4):

I just went through this problem. You might want to try firing up irb in the console and testing some of these out. 

**Example:**

```
$ irb
2.0.0-p353 :001 > long_string = %{
2.0.0-p353 :002"> It was the best of times,
2.0.0-p353 :003"> It was the worst of times.
2.0.0-p353 :004"> }
 => "\nIt was the best of times,\nIt was the worst of times.\n" 
2.0.0-p353 :005 > long_string.length
 => 54 
2.0.0-p353 :006 > long_string[0,1]
 => "\n"
```

It'll overwrite the previous assignment of long_string but if it helps to create a new session just to visualize it:

```
2.0.0-p353 :007 > exit
$ irb

2.0.0-p353 :001 > long_string = <<EOS
2.0.0-p353 :002"> It was the best of times,
2.0.0-p353 :003"> It was the worst of times.
2.0.0-p353 :004"> EOS
 => "It was the best of times,\nIt was the worst of times.\n" 
2.0.0-p353 :005 > long_string.length
 => 53 
2.0.0-p353 :006 > long_string[0,1]
=> "I"
```

I find this is a really useful tool for learning what's happening with my code.